# Add new line (\n) in Text Response from API.ai

Tags: javascript, node.js, api-ai

While using a Node.js module (`apiai`), I tried to add new lines (`\n`) in API.ai text response given a query result but it doesn't seem to work when I save the response in a variable from the callback like this:

```
request.on('response', function (response) {
  var textResponse = response.result.fulfillment.speech;
  // ...
})
```

Comment: how you tried? after adding \n what you have to do with that?

Comment: It gave me the `\n` literally. I tried by sending it to Facebook Messenger directly. It shows like this: `sample text \n sample text` but it should take a new line there.

Comment: i answered check my answer.

Comment: try  \u000A instead <\br>

Comment: No luck with that too.

Comment: did you try other options? check my comments in my answer

Comment: I tried all you said but didn't work. Finally I solved it in another way. Check my answer on own question. @Dinesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved it like this:

```
var textResponse = response.result.fulfillment.speech;
textResponse = textResponse.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
```

The input was like: `I'm a chatbot. \n built with ❤`

Comment: Did you mean textResponse.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>'); ?

Comment: I also got the newline to work....in the Dialogflow messenger. The newlines won't show up in the right panel of the main page.

Answer (score 1):

use Break-line `<\br>` instead of `\n`

For example:

```html
<div>This is with break line<br>this is after break line</div>
<div>This is with break line \n this is after new line</div>
```

Comment: I tried that. It's not working either. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/UU4HGQD.png

Comment: or use &nbsp; try this

Comment: or Insert <center></center> where you would normally put <br>

Comment: I tried all you said but didn't work. Finally I solved it in another way. Check my answer on own question. @Dinesh

Answer (score 0):

I was using the agent.add() method in the dialogflow inline editor and wanted a newline between some text.
so I used `"  \n"`( Two spaces followed by `\n`), and it gave the output as required on my dialogflow messenger integration.

eg.

`agent.add(firstName + " " + lastName + "  \n" + phoneno);`

Answer (score 0):

When entering a response, press Shift + Enter to input a newline or just Enter to input another text response.

The following limitations apply:

Max of 300 text entries per text response